# Error:org.ksoap2.Soapfault=null

Tags: android, ksoap2

There is no error in Web service
But there is an error

```
Error:org.ksoap2.Soapfault=null
```

pls help

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest ksoap2-android release (2.5.2).. it contains some fixes related to SoapFault. If there is still a problem, provide more detail here.